# How can i get a information / information box when the cursor goes over the button or any other item?

Tags: java, events, mouse, mouseevent, mouseover

There are buttons over which when we move our cursor a message telling what is the function of this button and other information is displayed. As soon as we move our mouse cursor away from the geometry of button , menuItem etc the information / information box vanishes .  How can i obtain this effect.
This is what i want :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the Tooltip Event

Could this Help for you?
[How to use Tool Tips](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)